# How do I import files from a folder without an __init__.py in python?

Tags: python, import, pythonpath

[image]
I saw some code of this format:

```
from b.c import *
```

However there is no `__init__.py` in `b` and I do not undersand how it succeeds.

---

The directory structure looks like this:

```
a.py
b
    c.py
```

Is it possible to `from b.c import *` in `a.py` even if there is no `__init__.py` in folder `b`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Wouldn't trying it out have been faster than writing the question?

Comment: I saw some code like from a.b.c import * and there is no __init__ in a and b. I don't know how it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Python 2.7 due to how the `PYTHONPATH` is constructed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for?lq=1) for an excellent explanation.

---

*However nothing is impossible in python...*

Thanks to [**PEP 420**: Implicit Namespace Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages): this is indeed possible in Python 3.3 and up.

`__init__.py` files are now optional for namespace packages:

### **Using Python 3.5 on Windows**

---

```
a.py
b/
    c.py
```

**b/c.py**

```
def hello_world():

    print("Hello World!")
```

**a.py**

```
from b.c import *

hello_world
```

Then:

```
>>> import a
Hello World!
```

More information about the caveats of namespace packages versus regular packages can be found in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) and in David Beazley's excellent talk
[*Modules and Packages: Live and Let Die!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0)

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from peak.util.decorators import *
>>> sys.modules['peak.util.decorators']
<module 'peak.util.decorators' from '/home/ubuntu/games/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peak/util/decorators.pyc'>
>>> 
(games)ubuntu@i:$ ll /home/ubuntu/games/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peak 
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul 18  2013 ./
drwxrwxr-x 75 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep 25 06:15 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 30 13:51 util/

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. Can you check peak/__init__.py? Maybe it defines the module directly